# Hexagon avatar with get_avatar()

Tags: avatar

I have the following code that fetches the avatar in WordPress

`<?php echo get_avatar(ThemexUser::$data['user']['ID'], 200); ?>`

and I would like to add the following clip-path into the avatar code:

`clip-path="url(#myClip)"`

How would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `extra_attr` input argument to add extra arguments to the gravatar's image tag:

```
<?php echo get_avatar( 
    ThemexUser::$data['user']['ID'], 
    200,                                            // size 
    '',                                             // default
    '',                                             // alt 
    [ 'extra_attr' => 'clip-path="url(#myClip)"' ]  // args
); ?>
```

but note that it's unescaped.

You could also add e.g. `class="hexagon"` with:

```
<?php echo get_avatar( 
    ThemexUser::$data['user']['ID'], 
    200,                                            // size 
    '',                                             // default
    '',                                             // alt 
    [ 'class' => 'hexagon']                         // args
); ?>
```

for easier use where:

```
.hexagon {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(
    50% 0, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0 75%, 0 25%
  );
  -moz-clip-path: polygon(
    50% 0, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0 75%, 0 25%
  );
  -ms-clip-path: polygon(
    50% 0, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0 75%, 0 25%
  );
  clip-path: polygon(
    50% 0, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0 75%, 0 25%
  );
}
```

where the hexagon definition is based on [this](https://codepen.io/darsain/pen/IqjFe) CodePen.

ps: I couldn't resist checking my gravatar in hexagon clip path ;-)

[image: hexagon]

Comment: You're welcome, glad to here it helped @NickGalgay